# How to destroy services that are programmatically injected into dynamically created angular components?

Tags: angular, angular-ivy

In Angular, it is possible to [load and view components dynamically at runtime](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) by calling `viewContainerRef.createComponent(factory)` on an instance of `ViewContainerRef`, passing a factory that can create an instance of the component.

By passing an `Injector` instance as third argument, it is possible to provide additional services (programmatically) to the dynamically loaded component (and its sub-components), e.g.:

```js
const injector = Injector.create({
    providers: [
        { provide: AdditionalService, useClass: AdditionalService },
    ],
    parent: parentInjector
});

const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(factory, undefined, injector);
```

However, the additional service is only instantiated, if the dynamically created component needs it - so we don't know, if the injector holds an instance of this service yet. Some time later, we destroy the dynamically created component:

```js
// some time later, we destroy the dynamically created component:
componentRef.destroy();
```

Unfortunately, destroying the component does not destroy the (possibly existing) service automatically! Also the injector does not provide a method for destruction, so it is not possible to destroy the additional service.

**How can we maintain the lifecycle (especially `ngOnDestroy()`) of those programmatically provided services correctly?**

*Note: I've implemented [a short example on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-v4gwqa) that demonstrates this behavior. It loads a component dynamically that requires two services. The first service is provided on component level (`@Component({ provides: [ FirstService ]}`), the second via injector as described above. When the component is destroyed, the first service is destroyed correctly while the second "stays alive".*

Comment: By declaring `provides: [ FirstService ]` in your component, you are making that service a non-singleton service and its lifecycle is tied directly to the components. Is there a reason you don't want to do that with `SecondService` as well? If you put `SecondService` in the providers array as well, it gets destroyed at the same time as the `FirstService`.

Comment: @peinearydevelopment good point. The component(s) are written by other department(s) and they should use `SecondService` as if it were a singleton service. In fact I'd like to provide a component-local service instead that proxies the real singleton service but adds some bookkeeping to ensure proper cleanup when the component gets destroyed.

Comment: @peinearydevelopment By the way: Even if I could add `SecondService` to the providers array - which would definitely solve my problem - it still seems that Angular's DI API misses a mechanism to cleanup programmatically provided services. Maybe a bug?

Comment: It could be you are right about the gap in Angular's api, but I doubt it. It is a pretty core api, used across the framework and it doesn't look like it is necessary. https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/b5ab7aff433a67cddaa55e621d17b1a1b07b57c2/packages/core/src/view/refs.ts#L367 I don't see an `Injector` destroyed explicitly in the framework, but I definitely could've missed it. If the managed classes are all small, it shouldn't be a problem. I can only anticipate a real memory issue if it is a cache with a lot of data in it.

Comment: I wonder if the injector.create also supports a viewProvider.. as that might get destroyed when the component gets destroyed..?

Comment: @peinearydevelopment I'm unsure about that. The `R3Injector` for example keeps track of its created instances and destroys them accordingly (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/b5ab7aff433a67cddaa55e621d17b1a1b07b57c2/packages/core/src/di/r3_injector.ts#L167). Unfortunately not public API...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution to the problem using a minimum of boilerplate code.

Solution: The injector created by `Injector.create(...)` is an `R3Injector`, which indeed tracks the instances and providers associated with it and also calls their lifecycle methods (`ngOnDestroy()`) when the injector itself is destroyed via its `destroy()` method. So by explicitely destroying the injector, all instances and providers get destroyed too. But as the `destroy()` method is not public API, we have to check for its existance first:

```ts
// CODE FROM THE QUESTION
const injector = Injector.create({
    providers: [
        { provide: AdditionalService, useClass: AdditionalService },
    ],
    parent: parentInjector
});

const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(factory, undefined, injector);

// ADDITIONAL CODE
// register a listener on the component reference to get notified
// when the component gets destroyed
componentRef.onDestroy(() => {
    // destroy injector if it is destroyable (i.e. has a destroy method)
    if (isDestroyable(injector)) injector.destroy();
});
```

The function `isDestroyable` can be implemented as [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```ts
interface Destroyable {
    destroy();
}

function isDestroyable(value: unknown): value is Destroyable {
    return value !== null && typeof value === 'object' &&
           typeof (value as Destroyable).destroy === 'function';
}
```

I've updated the [StackBlitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-v4gwqa) to demonstrate this solution.

Answer (score 0):

> Also the injector does not provide a method for destruction, so it is
> not possible to destroy the additional service.

There is `injector.destroy` which actually calls `SecondService.ngOnDestroy`. If you think about it - it seems logical but I failed to find any docs for this method at all...

Comment: No, the abstract `Injector` class does *not* have a `destroy` method, nor does [StaticInjector](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/27fdd52fb94942bb2e6caa1aa6429a804e248081/packages/core/src/di/injector.ts#L139), [ReflectiveInjector](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/27fdd52fb94942bb2e6caa1aa6429a804e248081/packages/core/src/di/reflective_injector.ts#L58) or [NodeInjector](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/27fdd52fb94942bb2e6caa1aa6429a804e248081/packages/core/src/render3/di.ts#L686) or `OutletInjector` or `NgAdapterInjector`. Even if some of them had, it's not public API.